# How to switch between user roles

Tags: users

I have three user roles

1. Merchant
2. Seller
3. End User

**Merchant** has more permissions privileges than **Seller**. **Merchant** can become a **seller** or an **end user**. When i created a user, i assigned all three roles to that user. But when the user is logged in, by default he should only have **Merchant** privileges. But he can switch to **seller** or **End use**r from a drop down. The user will not have all permission privileges (Merchant  + Seller + End User) at a time. He will only have a single role at a time. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of module available to do this job. Hope this will be helpful

**1. [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade)**

> The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with
>   enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no
>   password required). That person can switch back to their own user
>   account at any time.

**2. [Role Switcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleswitcher)**

> Role Switcher module provides with an option to change role for
>   testing purposes. It creates 'roleswitcher' role and grants it
>   permission to administer permissions which makes possible to switch
>   back to the original role the user had. The module provides a
>   roleswitcher block and a page, /roleswitcher.

Comment: Did you read the description of "Masquerade" ?
The Masquerade module allows site administrators (or anyone with enough permissions) to switch users and surf the site as that user (no password required). That person can switch back to their own user account at any time.
**It is not useful for  switch between roles!!!**
also Role switcher is not suitable for productive project( it is only for devel jobs)

Comment: I had gone through both. Why i am switching roles because i need to minimize the load of a user and make the things simple.

Comment: @drup they are not good solution for what you want, If I'll getting free I wrote better solution for you

Comment: @drup : what do you mean by "minimize load of a user"? I have the impression that you are rather looking for "a technique" to somehow organize (split)  the tasks to be completed by each of these 3 types (roles) of user, no? If that's what you want, then try to edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: I am showing certain blocks to each roles in a page. If the user has all roles (Merchant + Seller + End User), it will display all the blocks which makes the page complex. I need to avoid this.